# How to detect Entity Framework migration builder in .NET Core DbContext.OnConfiguring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

Is there a simple way to detect the `dotnet ef migrations add` program in my `DbContext.OnConfiguring` method? Only in that specific case, I want to use integrated security, otherwise username and password. Is there any standardized way to do so? Something like:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) {
    if (options.Context.IsModelBuilder)
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=***;Database=***;Integrated Security=True;");
    else
        options.UseSqlServer("Server=***;Database=***;user id=***;password=***;");
}
```

Comment: What EF version are you using? For me (EF 3.x), `dotnet ef migrations add` does not connect to real DB at all.

Comment: Version 3.1.1. The problem occurs, when you try to publish the changes to the database.